# Independent Auto-Number Sequence

Tags: ant, unit-test, production

How do I specify API 30.0's new Independent Auto-Number sequence feature for tests run while migrating code from Sandbox into Production?

I see the checkbox for this on Test Options, but how do you set it when using ANT to migrate code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the release notes for this feature ([New Independent Auto-Number Sequence Test Option](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/api/release-notes/rn_apex_autonumber_sequence.htm)), I would assume that this feature is enabled at the org level rather than at the test run level.

As you say, it is only exposed on the Test Options page:

[image: Independent Auto-Number Sequence]

So if you log into production and check this setting you should be all set.

**Disclaimer:** I've made a few assumptions here and haven't actually tested it. Results may vary! Feel free to correct me if I've got this wrong.

Comment: I changed the setting in Production and then created a Sandbox.  The setting was automatically in effect on the new sandbox (and deploying code with tests on the sandbox did not create gaps in the sequence #s).  I had to manually make the change on existing sandboxes.  Thanks...